# Deleting nodes also deletes relationships when using spring-data-neo4j, which is different from the cypher default

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm writing a spring-data-neo4j app, and playing around with CRUD.

In cypher, if I am not able to delete a node that has a relationship with another node, without first deleting the relationship.

In spring-data-neo4j that doesn't appear to have the same behaviour. When I delete a node, it also appears to delete the associated relationships too.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour from the default repository? How can I get spring-data to throw an exception given a deletion for a node with a relationship?

This is the behaviour I would expect (and desire):

```
@NodeEntity
class Junction {
    @GraphId Long id
}

@NodeEntity
class Route {
    @GraphId Long id
    @Fetch Junction from
    @Fetch Junction to
}

@Transactional
def "should not be able to delete a junction that is used"() {
    given: "a junction that is in use"
    Junction j = new Junction()
    Route r = new Route(from: j, to: new Junction())
    routeRepository.save(r)

    when: "the junction is removed"
    junctionRepository.delete(j)

    then:
    thrown SomeExceptionBecauseTheNodeHasAnAssociatedRelationship
}
```

Comment: Is the issue with your test? `Junction j` and `new Junction()` are going to be the same `null` ID node until they are saved. When you call delete(j) have you saved it previously and updated `j.id`?

Comment: No, that looks ok. The junction gets assigned an id when spring-data persists it.

Comment: Sure, but your code is risky (sure it's just a test). Can you confirm that j has an id in `junctionRepository.delete(j)` and that it equals `r.from.id`?

Comment: Yes :), a **assert j.id && j.id == r.from.id** is passing just fine.
The problem appears to be deeper, and I'm now pretty sure that it's to do with the integration test environment within grails. If I run the same code within the production code (grails run-app) the exception fires just fine.

Comment: Yes, the problem appears to be with the test framework, rather than with Neo4j :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the SDN repository delete methods are more akin to:

```
MATCH (j:Juntion)
OPTIONAL MATCH (j)-[r]-()
DELETE r, j
```

For me that is exactly what I want but if you want a different behaviour you could override the delete method in your junctionRepository interface like this:

```
@Override
@Query("MATCH (j:Junction) WHERE ID(j)={0} DELETE j")
public void delete(Long id);
```

Now if you try to delete a node with relationships you will get a `ConstraintViolationException` somewhere down the stack. The downside to this is that you'll have to remember to do it for each repository, to encourage you to remember you could introduce a deleteSafe idiom in your own interface and have each repository extend that (I guess the downside to interface composition is you still cannot force any interface to actually "implement" the new method).

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't appear to be working. The cypher is definitely running (if I introduce a syntax error in the @Query I get a cypher exception). But, the node is still being delete irrespective of the relationship. (I've confirmed that the relationship is being set up property by dumping the database before and after the call to **delete**). How could that be?

Comment: It cannot as far as I am aware, I just ran a test here and it definitely gave an exception - `HeuristicCompletionException` with a nested `org.neo4j.graphdb.ConstraintViolationException: Node record Node[15,used=false,rel=12,prop=-1,labels=Inline(0x0:[]),light] still has relationships`. Can you update your question with version information and SDN configuration?

Comment: Ok; it was running - but there's something about the integration test framework in grails that we preventing the test from working properly.